# Postgres array field prepend string to each of the array element

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgresDB, I have an array field, it looks like this

`id | lesson | years
1  | math   | {5,6}
2  | science | {4,5}`

How do I pre append a string, say `year` to each of the item in the years field,
`select id, lesson, func_append_to_array_item(year) from table`
it returns 

`id | lesson | years
1  | math   | {year 5, year 6}
2  | science | {year 4, year 5}`

Comment: if the array is int[], you cant

Answer (score 2):

if you want to just select it, you can use unnest + array_agg, eg:

```
t=# with c as (
  select id, lesson, concat('year ',unnest("year"))
  from "table"
)
select id, lesson,array_agg(concat) "year"
from c
group by id, lesson;
        year
---------------------
 {"year 5","year 6"}
(1 row)
```

But if you want to update the actual field, you first need to change array[] to array[]text in years column.

Also avoid reserved word in relation names please. Both `year` and `table` are SQL, not just words

**update**
As soon as OP updated the post and reflecting comments:

build:

```
t=# create table s125(id int, lesson text, years int[]);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into s125 values (1,'math','{5,6}'),(2,'science','{4,3}');
INSERT 0 2
t=# create or replace function s126(_y int[]) returns table (years text[]) as $$
begin
return query with c as (
  select concat('year ',unnest(_y))
)
select array_agg(concat) "years"
from c
;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

run:

```
t=# select id,lesson,s126(years) from s125;
 id | lesson  |        s126
----+---------+---------------------
  1 | math    | {"year 5","year 6"}
  2 | science | {"year 4","year 3"}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Sorry I am not a SQL guru, how do I write the SQL, so that it returns something like this

```
1  | math   | {year 5, year 6}
2  | science | {year 2, year 3}
```

Comment: got it - modified to include your fields

Comment: i would like to note that ARRAY_AGG doesn't guarantee the order, so you should also provide an ORDER BY statement